# Exact sequence of $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

> Let $0\longrightarrow N\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}M\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}L\longrightarrow0$
>   be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules. Prove that this chain splits iff
>   $f(N)$ is direct summand of $M$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;M=f(N)\oplus K\;$ , and define $\;F:M\to N\;$ by $\;F(m) = F(f(n)+k):=n\;$ . Show that $\;F\;$ is a well defined $\;R- $ homomorphism and $\;F\circ f=\text{Id}\,_N\;$ .

The other direction: suppose there exists an $\;R-$ homom. $\;F:M\to N\;$ s.t. $\;F\circ f=\text{Id}\,_N\;$. Show that

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\ker F\cap f(N)=\{0\}\\
(2)&\;\;M=f(N)\oplus\ker F\end{align*}$$

**Note:** Point (2) above may be a little tricky but not too much if you understand what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I will continue to try to prove

Comment: Can you explain more precise on the point (2)?

Comment: For $\;m\in M\;$, let $\;F(m)=n\in N\;$ , so take a peek at $$m=f(n)+\left(m-f(n)\right)\;\;\ldots\ldots$$